I have a long Menu in line, i don't want that collapse but i want continue on the next line when i make little
Sorry I Have this situation:
I have a long menu but I don't want that collapse, I want just continue on the next line
It is doing that but the result is horrible
This is the css
.navigation li, {
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.navigation a:link {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #2304d1;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


and this is the result

That is horrible...  I want that second line have distance from the first and don't overlay.
I have put margin top but nothing is happening....

Please provide full debugging details in the form of a [repro].

try giving your anchor tags a display of inline-block, so they respect their height. Also you probably want a flex container for a design like this, but you can definitely accomplish the design with or without it.

You need to provide more detailed information so that I can guide you

Pls provide your HTML for better help

The anchor tag wont respect height by default, give it a display of inline-block to have it calculate it's height in the layout.


body {
  margin: 0;
}

label {
  user-select: none;
}

.navigation {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.navigation li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation a {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18pt;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background: lightgreen;
}

#revert-a:checked ~ .navigation a {
  display: inline;
}
<label for="revert-a">
  Revert to inline elements
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="revert-a" />

<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">car</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">plane</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">food</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">hair</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">noise</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">car</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">plane</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">noise</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">car</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">plane</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">food</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">hair</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">noise</a></li>
</ul>




Hei I did not do anything... Instead I want ask you ... something without this "checkbox"

Lol thanks @AntonioGargiulo. Hopefully my answer makes sense to you, if you have any questions I'm happy to answer

Oh it looks like you edited your comment after I finished mine. You're wondering how to change the display without the checkbox? I can edit my answer to have the display changed by default.

Thank you very much async await
I have added only
display: inline-block;

and now everything is working as I wanted
.navigation a:link {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #2304d1;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

